# MiniProfiler for backend server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

We have two asp.net mvc apps - front-end and back-end.
Can I configure MiniProfiler http://miniprofiler.com/ to get statistic from the back-end app?

Comment: Yes you can.  I use it on my website.  It is amazing.  You could also look into Glimpse, which is a very powerful debugging tool with complete MVC support http://getglimpse.com/
It has many plugins you can use too, and you can easily manage it to switch it on/off for dev/debug/production modes.

Comment: I would recommend going ahead and try to install/run both.  They are very straight forward to set up using Nuget.  Make sure you install the MiniProfiler.MVC package for MVC backend support.

Comment: I installed MiniProfiler both to backend and frontend, but I see only frontend statistic in my browser.

Comment: Thank you for Glimpse advice - I will try it as soon as possible

Comment: Yes, those statistics do represent what happened on the server side though. :)
Are you wanting the logs to be written to file on the server?

Comment: No :) I want to see how long works my backend mvc app, but I see statistic only from frontend mvc app (http://screencast.com/t/X2ON1lZdh)

Comment: Those statistics you are seeing includes the backend processing.  Expand the view and you can see how long it took for the request to process.  

For e.g. from the MiniProfiler website: http://i.imgur.com/PsjLY.png - This shows the "backend" blocks. i.e. Application_BeginRequest, OnActionExecuting etc.  

That is your service side code, which handles the request, being timed.

Comment: Yes, it's work fine if you have only one mvc application. I have two different MVC applications on IIS. One of them Frontend.App - it renders pages and has a static content. For it I can see how long it took to render for example an Index page. But I have also another MVC application - Backend.App - it works like REST-service and doesn't render anything. It just process ajax requests from client. I want to see statistic also from that app

Comment: Ah, that information is very important. :)  Miniprofiler supports AJAX requests too, but only if they are running on the same web instance I believe.  This is trickier as they are separate application instances.  Do they have to be separate, or can the 'REST' app be integrated into the other?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, they have to be on different applications. So I think there is no build-in feature for it. Anyway, Sean, thank you for help!